# Javascript - Incorrectly defined function

Tags: javascript

This the javascript function:

```
//set cookies
function setCookie (cname, cvalue) {
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    var expireTime = time + 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365;

    now.setTime(expireTime);

    document.cookie = cname + '=' + cvalue + ';expires=' + now.toGMTString() + ';path=/';
}
```

The error occurs when I call the function from another javascript file:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    setCookie("showAdminUser", false);    
});
```

This is the error in Crhome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: setCookie is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

I have thought, that the function was still missing a "return", but it keeps giving me the error in console:

```
//set cookies
function setCookie (cname, cvalue) {
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    var expireTime = time + 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365;

    now.setTime(expireTime);

    document.cookie = cname + '=' + cvalue + ';expires=' + now.toGMTString() + ';path=/';

    return document.cookie;
}
```

What could be the problem? thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you include the file with the function before you call it?

Comment: Are you referencing both Javascript files in the mentioned page? If so, how? The error is self explanatory: one script doesn't know about the other.

Comment: is `function setCookie` defined in the global scope exactly how you've shown it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like problem with managing resource files, not programming error.

JavaScript functions don't require a return statement, not having one is completly fine.

Just as a sanity check, try copying the function to the same file you're using it in. If it works, the problem is somewhere in the order of `<script src=...` tags, scope visibility, or somewhere else similar, I would guess.

Comment: If that's why it seemed strange to me, it does not require a return, I will do the test you indicate me, thank you

Comment: Exactly am not loading the file well, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error is because that you are not having the setCookie function defined is second file . there are multiple solutions :

1. **import statment**:
   lets imagine that the setCookie function is in file1.js and the file that you have called setCookie  in , is in file2.js 
   So you should export `setCookie` in file1.js:

```js
export function setCookie (cname, cvalue) {
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    var expireTime = time + 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365;

    now.setTime(expireTime);

    document.cookie = cname + '=' + cvalue + ';expires=' + now.toGMTString() + ';path=/';
```

and import it in file2:

```js
import {setCookie} from "./file1.js"
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    setCookie("showAdminUser", false);    
});
```

2. in html , every script that is in top would be automatically imported in below files . so your html have to be like this:

```html
<script src="./file1.js"></script>
<script src="./file2.js"></script>
```

if you are using first solution , remeber to add `type="module"` to script tag if you get error.

Comment: also , do not copy the file1.js in file2.js cause it makes your file heavier.